# Help reading a phase diagram?

Tags: physical-chemistry

How does the y axis work? If the pressure I am looking for is 10^‐4 to 10^‐3 nbar? I tried doing log of  the yaxis but its giving me numbers that are not even close to what I am looking for.
[image]

Comment: We have a policy which states that ‎you should show your thoughts and/or efforts into solving the problem. It'll make us certain that ‎we aren't doing your homework for you. 
Basically any question with the wording your question has is considered homework; it needn't be literally one. Self-study questions, puzzles etc. also count as homework. 

Don't worry, they're not banned. But, we require a minimal effort. Otherwise, this question may get closed.‎ Please [edit] in your full reasoning or thoughts on this.

See [Homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/141/7448)

Comment: What base are you using when applying the log? $log_e(10)=2.3$ whereas $log_{10}(10)=1$. Looks like you're using base 10. For sulfur dioxide the triple point is at a pressure in bar of $log_{10}(P)=-1.8$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how the y-axis works :

[image]